# Unsafe conversion

Tags: c, pointers, type-conversion, type-safety

Is the following conversion safe?

```
int b[10][10];
char *x;
int a[]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
  for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
    b[i][j]=a[i];

for(x=(char *)&b[0];x<=(char *)&b[9][9];x+=sizeof(a+1)) // Problem lies here!
    printf("%d\n",*x);
```

I don't think the above conversion in the `for` loop is safe (I think it is platform dependent). Please correct me if I am wrong. I am surprised because the code compiles without giving any warnings even when compiled using the `-Wall -pedantic` options in gcc.

Comment: I assumed it was a mistyped b. I could be wrong though...

Comment: `a` has 9 elements, you're accessing `a[9]`.  You also have a semicolon missing.  Therefore, you need two more "Problem lies here comments" :-)

Comment: I didn't downvote, though - those are minor typos.

Comment: I accidentally upvoted, and then accidentally clicked the down button instead of re-clicking the up button to undo my upvote. Now the system won't let me take back my vote.

Comment: @Alok: Corrected! 

@Andrew: Try it now.

Comment: @Prasoon, you're still missing a semicolon. :-)

Comment: Uff! something is surely wrong with me today :-(

Comment: I will ask the obvious: what are you trying to do?  Is this your code?

Comment: @Alok: No, it is not my code. It is a puzzle from ITBHU's coding event codefest. http://itbhu.ac.in/codefest/problem.php?pid=16

Comment: @Prasoon: In that case you have a erroneous semicolon right after the `for` header. `printf` was apparently intended to be the body of the cycle.

Comment: There is no `sizeof(a+1)` there.  Oh I see.  You tried that as a solution.  I think your solution is correct.  I would use `sizeof(1,a)` just for kicks.

Comment: @Prasoon: No, because the second program takes `sizeof(a)`, which is `sizeof(int *)`, so the first program needs an expression that gives you the same value.  On my computer, `sizeof(int) != sizeof(int *)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This whole thing has a chance of being legal for one and only one reason: the 2D `int` array object is reinterpreted as an array of `char` objects. While in general case memory reinterpretation leads to undefined behavior, the language specification explicitly allows "array of [signed/unsigned] char" reinterpretations for objects of any type.

However, one formal safety problem is still there. The language does not guarantee that any bit pattern is a valid value of `char` type. Your attempt to read reinterpreted memory through `char` type can theoretically cause undefined behavior if it encounters trap representation for `char`. In order to be safe here you have to use the `unsigned char` type, which is the only type that has no trap representations. Of course, a platform with a trapping `char` can be safely called "exotic".

Meanwhile, your `sizeof(a + 1)` doesn't seem to make any sense. `a + 1` is an expression of `int *` type. Why you'd want to use the pointer size to increment your `x` value in this case is not clear to me. What were you trying to achieve?

As for the absence of warnings... I wouldn't expect the compiler to issue any warnings here. GCC often warns about type-punning (aka memory reinterpretation), but since `char` reinterpretations are explicitly allowed (as I said above), there's no warning here. Moreover, explicit casts usually tend to suppress any warnings, since they are a way of telling the compiler that you do actually want to do something regardless of how wrong and/or dangerous it might be.

Comment: @Andrey T: _a + 1 is an expression of int * type_ And that is what I want. It is a puzzle from an online coding competition.

Comment: @Prasoon: By the way your cycle looks, I'd expect one to use `sizeof(int)` here, like `sizeof(a[1])` or `sizeof(*(a + 1))` or `sizeof(*a)`. As for `sizeof(a + 1)`, again, I don't understand what is the point of this. It makes no sense to me.

Comment: I have assumed the sizeof(int) and sizeof(int *) to be the same on that particular platform. Yes I think sizeof(*a) looks more correct.

Comment: Yeah, why write `sizeof(a+1)` instead of `sizeof(int *)`?  On my macbook, it prints each number 5 times, because `sizeof(int *)` is 2 times `sizeof(int)`.

Comment: Yeah that was a "big" mistake I was making. Thanks for suggesting the necessary corrections :)

Comment: The language my not guarantee that any bit pattern is a valid `char` but it's not worth loosing sleep over.  There are no CPU architectures in common use where a char might trap, and no forseeable future CPU that might want to change that.  This is a case where the language allows something that no-one wants to do.

Answer (score 1):

a cast of any pointer type to char* is explicitly allowed by the C language. so most of this is fine.

```
for(x=(char *)&b[0]; x <= (char *)&b[9][9]; x += sizeof(a+1))
```

The first part is fine `x = (char*)&b[0];` establishes a char pointer to the beginning of the array.  The test is also fine  `x <= (char *)&b[9][9]` will be true as long as x points inside the array.

`x += sizeof(a+1)` is the iffy part.  On most 32 bit CPU architectures sizeof(int*) just *happens* to be the same as sizeof(int), so this code will probably *work*, but only by accident.

I'm sure what was intended was `x += sizeof(a[0])` or `x += sizeof(b[0])`, but since the code actually did what was intended, no-one noticed the bug.